# How to convert a "binary" String literal of 256 chars into a hexadecimal notation?

Tags: java, hex

I have 0 and 1 String type combination with total 256 length.

How can I convert it to hexadecimal?

I can do it with combination for 64 or less length, but cant do the same when the length is 256

could you help me please? Any example?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to use `BigInteger`. It's capable to convert String of any length as long as you have enough memory:

```
String str = "100010110101...";
String hex = new BigInteger(str, 2).toString(16);
```

It's also not very difficult to implement this conversion without using the intermediate `BigInteger` just splitting the input string into fixed length chunks (works for arbitrary length input strings as well):

```
public static String binToHex(String str) {
    int l = str.length();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int cur = 0;
    for (int next = l - l / 32 * 32; next <= l; next += 32) {
        result.append(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(
                str.substring(cur, next), 2)));
        cur = next;
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```